# Having trouble with Postgres unnest array syntax

Tags: arrays, postgresql, insert

I am looking for guidance on the best way to do this insert. I am trying to create 11 entries for `role_id 58385` while looping through the values of each of these arrays. I am new to PostgreSQL and need some guidance as to what I am doing wrong in this instance.

```
INSERT INTO public.acls (role_id, acl_id, update, can_grant, retrieve, create, archive) VALUES (
           '58385', 
           unnest(array[1,14,20,21,22,24,25,26,36,300,302]), 
           unnest(array[f,f,t,t,f,f,f,t,f,t,t]), 
           unnest(array[f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f]), 
           unnest(array[t,t,t,t,t,t,t,t,t,t,t]), 
           unnest(array[f,f,t,t,f,f,f,t,f,t,t]), 
           unnest(array[f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f])
           )
```

Do I need a `SELECT` subquery for each of the arrays? Or could I make one array from the six and Insert them.

Comment: I am curious. Why this complicated syntax instead of simple `values()` clause with constant values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single `select` will do it for you, but `t` and `f` will need to be `true` and `false`:

```
select '58385',
           unnest(array[1,14,20,21,22,24,25,26,36,300,302]),
           unnest(array[false,false,true,true,false,false,false,true,false,true,true]),
           unnest(array[false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false]),
           unnest(array[true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true]),
           unnest(array[false,false,true,true,false,false,false,true,false,true,true]),
           unnest(array[false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false])
;
 ?column? | unnest | unnest | unnest | unnest | unnest | unnest 
----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------
 58385    |      1 | f      | f      | t      | f      | f
 58385    |     14 | f      | f      | t      | f      | f
 58385    |     20 | t      | f      | t      | t      | f
 58385    |     21 | t      | f      | t      | t      | f
 58385    |     22 | f      | f      | t      | f      | f
 58385    |     24 | f      | f      | t      | f      | f
 58385    |     25 | f      | f      | t      | f      | f
 58385    |     26 | t      | f      | t      | t      | f
 58385    |     36 | f      | f      | t      | f      | f
 58385    |    300 | t      | f      | t      | t      | f
 58385    |    302 | t      | f      | t      | t      | f
(11 rows)
```